# Regex Action in Nintex workflow only replace first instance

Tags: .net, regex, nintex-workflow

I have a Nintex Workflow for a SharePoint 2013 list, and am trying to use the Regular Expressions Action to edit a string. I believe Nintex uses the Microsoft .NET standard for Regex. I am trying to remove the FIRST occurrence of a parenthesis in a string. Here is my input text:

```
Douglas Christopher W) I have some (comments) to add.
```

Using Regex, I can use the Pattern

```
\)
```

And the Replacement Text

```
:
```

But that will change ALL the occurrences of the ) character, returning

```
Douglas Christopher W: I have some (comments: to add.
```

How do I turn off the global flag and just convert the first instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use a capturing group matching not a closing parenthesis `[^)]*` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) followed by matching the closing parenthesis.

I the replacement refer to the capturing group followed by a `:`

```
^([^)]*)\)
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5b%5e%29%5d*%29%5c%29&i=Douglas+Christopher+W%29+I+have+some+%28comments%29+to+add.&r=%241%3a)

Replace with:

```
$1:
```

Comment: Thank you, I was adding \) within the square brackets, I can just use ). That's what was throwing me off.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
(?<=^[^)]*)\)
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%5b%5e%29%5d*%29%5c%29&i=Douglas+Christopher+W%29+I+have+some+%28comments%29+to+add.&r=%3a)

**Details**

- `(?<=^[^)]*)` - a positive lookbehind that requires the text immediately to the right to match `^[^)]*` pattern: start of string followed with no `)` chars
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Result:

[image]